# Find the minimum of $(a-b)^2+(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2$ for reals $a \ge 4b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,$ be real numbers such that $a\ge 4b$ .
> Find the minimum of $(a-b)^2+(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2$.

This problem is  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=553680

Comment: a=b=1 is the correct solution and the minimum is 0

Comment: @JoseGarcia $a\geq4b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum is either on the interior of the feasible set, or on the boundary.

The gradient of the objective is
$$\left[2(a-b)+2(a-1), -2(a-b)+2(b-1)\right] = \left[4a-2b-2, 4b-2a-2\right],$$
and so the unconstrained minimum is the infeasible point $(1,1)$. Therefore the minimum is on the boundary. Substituting $a=4b$ gives 
$$\min_b\ (3b)^2 + (4b-1)^2 + (b-1)^2 = \min_b\ 26b^2-10b+2.$$
The gradient is  $52b-10$, so $b=\frac{5}{26}$ and the minimum is $\frac{27}{26}$.

Comment: "The minimum is either on the interior of the feasible set, or on the boundary." How do you justify this?

Comment: Given sufficient regularity conditions (which are trivially satisfied in this problem) the KKT conditions hold: at every critical point $0 = \nabla f(x) + \lambda \nabla g(x)$, where $f$ is the objective and $g$ the constraint, with $\lambda g = 0$. If $\lambda=0$ the minimum is also an unconstrained minimum $0 = \nabla f$. If not, $g=0$ and you are on the boundary.

Comment: I see that I phrased my question badly. Obviously the minimum value of the objective function in the feasible set is either in its interior or on its boundary! What I meant was: Just because we know that the _global_ minimum is outside the feasible set, why does that imply that the minimum in the feasible set is on its boundary? And I see that it is because the objective function has just one local minimum (which lies outside the feasible set). Unless I have misunderstood you, I don't think regularity conditions are sufficient.

Comment: They're not, but the objective is convex so there is only one unconstrained critical point.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  Let $a=4b+c^2$.  You can minimize the resulting function of $b$ and $c$, without worrying about a boundary.

Comment: That is very cheeky ;)

Comment: @Daron, I didn't see your answer until after posting my own.  Interesting that we both used a $c$!

Answer (score 1):

Set $a = 4b + c\ $ and then minimize the function $f(b,c) = (4b +c -b)^2 + (4b+c-1)^2 + (b-1)^2$ using the standard derivative test. The function will be at a minimum on the half-plane where it is defined either a local minimum, or along the boundary, which is where $c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: Here is a solution without calculus.
Similar trick is used in e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679556/maximize-sum-limits-mathrmcyc-a-for-a2b2c2d2a3b5c7d-4/4711102#4711102).

We have the following identity
\begin{align*}
 &(a - b)^2 + (a - 1)^2 + (b - 1)^2\\
 ={}& \frac{27}{26} + \frac{9}{13}(a - 4b)
 + 2\left(a - \frac{b}{2} - \frac{35}{52}\right)^2
 + \frac{3}{2}\left(b - \frac{5}{26}\right)^2.
\end{align*}

Thus, we have
$(a - b)^2 + (a - 1)^2 + (b - 1)^2 \ge \frac{27}{26}$ for all real numbers $a\ge 4b$.

Also, when $a = 10/13, b = 5/26$, we have $(a - b)^2 + (a - 1)^2 + (b - 1)^2 = 27/26$.

Thus, the minimum of $(a - b)^2 + (a - 1)^2 + (b - 1)^2$ subject to $a \ge 4b$
is $\frac{27}{26}$
when $b = \frac{5}{26}$ and $a = \frac{10}{13}$ (satisfying $a = 4b$).

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Remarks*: How to obtain this identity?

We use the method of unknown coefficients.

We hope to find constants $M$ and $\alpha \ge 0$ such that
$$f(a, b) := (a - b)^2 + (a - 1)^2 + (b - 1)^2 - M - \lambda (a - 4b) $$
is non-negative for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.
If so, we have $(a-b)^2+(a-1)^2 + (b-1)^2 \ge M$
for reals $a\ge 4b$.
Furthermore, when $a = 4b$, we have $(a-b)^2+(a-1)^2 + (b-1)^2 \ge M$.

We complete the square in two variables ($a$ and $b$), one at a time. We have
$$f(a, b)
= 2\left(a - \frac{\lambda}{4} - \frac{b}{2} - \frac12\right)^2
+ \frac32\left(b - 1 + \frac76\lambda\right)^2
- M - \frac{13}{6}\lambda^2 + 3\lambda.$$

Solving the system of
\begin{align*}
 a - \frac{\lambda}{4} - \frac{b}{2} - \frac12
 &= 0, \\
 b - 1 + \frac76\lambda &= 0, \\
 - M - \frac{13}{6}\lambda^2 + 3\lambda &= 0,\\
 a - 4b &= 0.
\end{align*}
we have
$\lambda = \frac{9}{13}$ and $M = \frac{27}{26}$.