# Maximize $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} a$ for $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+a+3b+5c+7d=4$

Tags: optimization, contest-math, quadratics, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization

> If $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+a+3b+5c+7d=4$, find the maximal value of $a+b+c+d$.

Hi there, I found this problem in an old Serbian contest archive. It's dated to $2002$, but I can't find any solution online or in the archive (archive is, inconveniently, only problems). I'm not sure where to start here as they're not positive real numbers so I can't use some of the more popular inequalities and it's also really puzzling on how to find a connection between $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ and $a+b+c+d$ as the numbers can be in between $-1,0,1$. I'd really appreciate some help here, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

first make whole squares of all terms.
Add $\frac{1}{4},\frac{9}{4},\frac{25}{4},\frac{49}{4}$

So you get
$$ ( a^2+2(\frac{1}{2})a+(\frac{1}{2})^2 ) + ( b^2+2(\frac{3}{2})b+(\frac{3}{2})^2 )+ ( c^2+2(\frac{5}{2})c+(\frac{5}{2})^2 )+( d^2+2(\frac{7}{2})d+(\frac{7}{2})^2 ) $$$$= 4+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{9}{4}+\frac{25}{4}+\frac{49}{4}$$

this implies

$$(a+\frac{1}{2})^2+(b+\frac{3}{2})^2+(c+\frac{5}{2})^2+(d+\frac{7}{2})^2 = 25$$

Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

So

$${(a+\frac{1}{2})+(b+\frac{3}{2})+(c+\frac{5}{2})+(d+\frac{7}{2})} \leq \sqrt{{(a+\frac{1}{2})^2+(b+\frac{3}{2})^2+(c+\frac{5}{2})^2+(d+\frac{7}{2})^2}}*\sqrt{4}$$

Solving gives
$$a+b+c+d \leq 2$$

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ don't have to be positive, how do you use $RMS-AM$

Comment: assume any specific value of $(a+1/2)^2, (b+3/2)^2 etc .$ for which you get 25 as sum their sum.  let's say you take (a+1/2)^2=1 . for this you will have two-two values of a,b,c,d. The value you will get by taking positive square root will  be greater than negative one. So for maximising sum you take the positive one.

Comment: The solution is fine to me however I would add the need to complete the squares on the left side in order to explain it. Or if you have a better explanation please do insert it for clarity.

Comment: Using CS instead of QM-AM maybe a simpler choice and avoid the issue of negative numbers.  Also you need to demonstrate the maximum can be achieved, else this remains just an upper bound.  $(2, 1, 0,-1)$ is a case which achieves this bound, so in fact you have found the maximum. +1

Answer (score 0):

*Remark*: Here is a solution which gives not only the maximum but also the minimum. To find them, we simply complete the square of quadratic functions.

**Answer**: The maximum of $a + b + c + d$ is $2$ when $a = 2, b = 1, c = 0, d = -1$.

The minimum of $a + b + c + d$ is $-18$ when $a = -3, b = -4, c = -5, d = -6$.

**Proof**.

Let $x = a + b + c + d$.

Using $d = x - a - b - c$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + a + 3b + 5c + 7d - 4\\
 ={}& 2\,{a}^{2}+ \left( 2\,b+2\,c-2\,x-6 \right) a \\
 &\qquad +2\,{b}^{2}+2\,bc-2\,xb+2
 \,{c}^{2}-2\,xc+{x}^{2}-4\,b-2\,c+7\,x-4\\[6pt]
 ={}& 2\left(a - \frac{-b - c + x + 3}{2} \right)^2
 + \frac32\,{b}^{2}+ \left( -1+c-x \right) b \\[6pt]
 &\qquad +\frac32\,{c}^{2}+4\,x+c+\frac12\,{x}^{2}
 -xc- \frac{17}{2}\\[6pt]
 ={}& 2\left(a - \frac{-b - c + x + 3}{2} \right)^2 + \frac32\left(b - \frac{1 + x - c}{3}\right)^2\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{4}{3}\,{c}^{2}+ \left( -\frac23\,x+\frac43 \right) c+\frac{11}{3}\,x-{\frac {26}{3}}+\frac13
 \,{x}^{2}\\[6pt]
 ={}& 2\left(a - \frac{-b - c + x + 3}{2} \right)^2 + \frac32\left(b - \frac{1 + x - c}{3}\right)^2 + \frac43\left(c - \frac{x-2}{4}\right)^2\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{(x + 18)(x - 2)}{4}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
(*Note*: We complete the square in three variables ($a$, $b$ and $c$), one at a time.)

From (1), we have
$$\frac{(x + 18)(x - 2)}{4} \le 0$$
which results in $-18 \le x \le 2$.

1. $x = 2$

From (1), we have
$$a - \frac{-b - c + x + 3}{2} = b - \frac{1 + x - c}{3}
= c - \frac{x-2}{4} = 0$$
which results in $a = 2, b = 1, c = 0$.

Thus, the maximum of $a + b + c + d$ is $2$ when $a = 2, b = 1, c = 0, d = -1$.

2. $x = -18$

From (1), we have
$$a - \frac{-b - c + x + 3}{2} = b - \frac{1 + x - c}{3}
= c - \frac{x-2}{4} = 0$$
which results in $a = -3, b = -4, c = -5$.

Thus, the minimum of $a + b + c + d$ is $-18$ when $a = -3, b = -4, c = -5, d = -6$.

We are done.

---

$\phantom{2}$

**Discussion**.

Here we introduce a trick which I have used to prove
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449755/prove-that-a-d2b-c2-geq-1-6-if-a24b2-4-and-cd-4/4539078#4539078).

Once we motivate our solutions by some way, we can give the following simpler solutions.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &2 - (a + b + c + d) + \frac15(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 +a + 3b + 5c + 7d - 4)\\
 ={}& \frac15(a - 2)^2 + \frac15(b - 1)^2 + \frac15c^2 + \frac15(d + 1)^2 \\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
which gives $a + b + c + d \le 2$.

On the other hand, we have
\begin{align*}
 &a + b + c + d + 18 + \frac15(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 +a + 3b + 5c + 7d - 4)\\
 ={}& \frac15(a + 3)^2 + \frac15(b + 4)^2 + \frac15(c + 5)^2 + \frac15(d + 6)^2 \\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
which gives $a + b + c + d \ge -18$.