# Find minimum of $a^2+\cdots+e^2$ under $2$ quadratic constraints

Tags: inequality, optimization

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ be real numbers such that
> $$ab+bc+cd+de+ea=20,\\ac+bd+ce+da+eb=22.$$
> Find, as the root of a polynomial, the minimum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2$.

The numeric value of this minimum seems to be about $23.2359$.

I also tried Lagrange Multipliers but it didn't work.

Perhaps we could use some substitutions to eliminate the condition.

**Update**. I have proven that the problem is *equivalent* to (but no having the same answer as) the problem of minimizing
$$\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2+(d-e)^2+(e-a)^2}{ac+bd+ce+da+eb-ab-bc-cd-de-ea}.$$

**Update** River Li finding the answer "$21+\sqrt5$" enabled me to produce the following natural solution that explores the essence of this problem (at least I think it does)

Here is the full process of my thinking.

We are to prove that $\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}a^2\ge21+\sqrt5$, or (by the first condition)
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2+(d-e)^2+(e-a)^2\ge2+2\sqrt5.\tag1$$
This, perceptually, means that the variables $a\dots$, $e$ must not stick too close to each other. So we will observe their differences by subtracting the conditions:
$$a(b-c)+b(c-d)+c(d-e)+d(e-a)+e(a-b)=2.\tag2$$
Notice that if we increase each variable by $t\in\Bbb R$, then $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not affected. This means that given arbitrary numbers $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ such that
$$A(B-C)+B(C-D)+C(D-E)+D(E-A)+E(A-B)=2,$$
we are likely to be able to add $t\in\Bbb R$ to each of them so that the result $A'=A+t$ and similar satisfy
$$A'B'+B'C'+C'D"+D'E'+E'A'=20.$$
Then we must also have $A'C'+\cdots+E'B'=22$. Moreover, as we just said, the addition doesn't affect $(1)$. Therefore: *the numbers $22$ and $20$ are inessential. What's vital is that $22-20=\bf\color{red}2$.* So the problem becomes:

> Given real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ such that
> $$a(b-c)+b(c-d)+c(d-e)+d(e-a)+e(a-b)=2,$$
> prove that $\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}(a-b)^2\ge2+2\sqrt5$.

The proof is straightforward. It suffices to show that
$$\sum_{\rm cyc}(a-b)^2\ge\left(1+\sqrt5\right)\sum_{\rm cyc}a(b-c),\tag3$$
which is easily true by Lagrangian SOS method.

Now we expand $(3)$, and the result is equivalent to River Li's identity!

Comment: Is this problem a constest math problem? If yes, we can hope for a nice solution. If no, I doubt whether an analytical solution exists.

Comment: @NN2 It is not a contest problem.

Comment: "As a root of a polynomial" I doubt you have come up with this yourself. What is the source?

Comment: @Downvoters: Why did you put $-1$? I don't want to believe because you cannot solve the problem so explain your reasons please.

Comment: @DS It is well known that any sort of "best constant" for algebraic inequalities is an algebraic number, although it might not have surd form. Hence I asked for a polynomial.

Comment: OP, you are lucky that this question can have a nice solution (me too, I learn a new technique). I give you an upvote to compensate the two downvotes you got. :)

Comment: It is pertinent, I think, to remark that if $f(x)=0$ where $f$ is the polynomial having the roots $a,b,c,d,e$ then the coefficient of  $x^3$ is $42$.

Comment: I'm guessing that the downvotes are related to the post being considered low-quality. Esp for these inequality questions, just stating the problem and "I was unsuccessful" is considered insufficient, even though personally I think it's hard to provide much more context.  That update might help substantiate that you've been thinking about this, esp if additional details were provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Remark.* Use the trick in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449755/prove-that-a-d2b-c2-geq-1-6-if-a24b2-4-and-cd-4/4539078#4539078).

The minimum is $21 + \sqrt{5} \approx 23.23606798$.

**Proof.**

We have
\begin{align*}
 &a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 - (21 + \sqrt{5})\\[6pt]
  ={}& \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}(ab + bc + cd + de + ea - 20) + \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}(ac + bd + ce + da + eb -22)\\[6pt]
  &\qquad + \frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{32}(b\sqrt{5} + c\sqrt{5} -2e\sqrt{5} - 2a + 3b + 3c - 2d - 2e)^2\\[6pt]
  &\qquad + \frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{32}(b\sqrt{5} - c\sqrt{5} + 2a - b + c - 2d)^2\\[6pt]
  \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
with equality if
\begin{align}
 &a = d =  \frac15\,\sqrt {110+4\,\sqrt {135+80\,\sqrt {5}}+4\,\sqrt {5}},\\
 &b = c = \frac15\,\sqrt {100-2\,\sqrt {-510+310\,\sqrt {5}}+4\,\sqrt {5}},\\
 &e = -\frac{ab + bc + cd - 20}{a+d}.
\end{align}

Comment: +1. But how do you guess the coefficients $(1\pm \sqrt 5)/2$, $\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{32}$,...

Comment: @NN2 Not guess. You can find constants $M, p, q$ such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 - M - p(ab + bc + cd + de + ea - 20) - q(ac + bd + ce + da + eb -22)$ is something like completing the squares. The idea is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679556/maximize-sum-limits-mathrmcyc-a-for-a2b2c2d2a3b5c7d-4/4711102#4711102)

Comment: I like this technique!

Comment: Interesting. Is the problem of finding $M$, $p$, $q$ such that the rest is a sum of squares what we call "SDP problem"?

Comment: @youthdoo Yes. For quadratic function here, I think it is completing the squares in variables $e, \cdots$, one at a one.

Comment: I have a method that can smoothly determine $M$, $p$, $q$, and it is based on the "update" in the question!

Comment: @youthdoo Your proof in the update is very nice.